# Google Analytics - Full URL for Pages

Tags: url, google-analytics

I need to see full webpage URLs for my analysis (e.g. www.website.co.uk/pages) not just the URIs (e.g. /pages), so I've applied the filter described here:

https://splitter.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/178552-how-to-show-the-domain-part-of-a-url-in-google-ana

This works well on the Real-Time Report - it does indeed show the full URLs here. But if I go to "What pages do your users visit?", or if I generate a custom report etc, the pages still only show the URI part of the address - which is no good to me.

Why is this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Google Analytics safes your Domainname as a dimension called Hostname. So if you want to get a report 8 for example Landing Pages) just add Hostname as a second Dimension to this report und you see your "full URL".

[image]

[image]

If you want to do this through the API its called ga:hostname

Comment: Brilliant! I've been fretting over this for ages :)